# File API: reader vs. event.target

Tags: javascript, html, fileapi

I have studied many articles and posts to learn about File API and still don't understand why almost all of them use `event.target` instead of `reader`. Here are three examples:

1. [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#introduction)
2. [Using files from web applications | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications#Example.3A_Showing_thumbnails_of_user-selected_images)
3. [Working with files in JavaScript, Part 2: FileReader | NCZOnline](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/05/15/working-with-files-in-javascript-part-2/)

The last reference even recommends using `event.target`:

> The FileReader instance is available inside of the event handler via
>   event.target and it’s recommended to use that instead of referencing
>   the reader variable directly.

But why is it recommended and widely used? What's wrong with using `reader` or simpler `this` instead: <kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Mori/tJBHZ/)**</kbd>

I know `this` and `event.target` can be different, but in this case they both refer to the `FileReader` object.

- `reader`: an instance of `FileReader`;
- `onload`: a [FileReader event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader#Event_handlers);
- `result`: a [FileReader property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader#Properties);

While you can use `reader.onload`, then why not `reader.result`?

Comment: There is no specific reason.if you are sure `this` will be a `FileReader` you can use this.Nobody is recommanding anything.

Comment: People use `event.target` by default because it's a standard. Also there may be cases where you pass on the event object to another event handler, and for whatever reason the context was not set to `FileReader`, which means `this` is not `FileReader` Object now, but `event.target` is... It pretty much ends up with whatever you feel like you want to do...

Answer (score 0):

The reader variable may not be in scope:

```
(function() {
    // variables defined in this IIFE are not visible outside
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener("load", processText);
    // ...
})();

function processText(event) {
    // `event.target` works here
    // `reader` will not work
    //     because the scope of this function does not include `reader`
]
```

This is a contrived example, but the problem could manifest in any real situation where your callback and your reader varaible declaration are in different scopes, or where a single function acts as an event listener for multiple readers (e.g., `reader1.onload = readText; reader2.onload = readText;`).

As for using `this` versus `event.target`, that seems be purely a matter of personal preference.